# Составить подпрограмму для поиска минимума функции

Tags: c++, функции

> Составить подпрограмму определения минимума функции у = f(х), заданной
> в дискретных точках  отрезка [а, b] с постоянным шагом h. Используя
> ее, найти минимумы функций: y1 = sin^2х * соsх – 1n|х| на отрезке
> [0.1; 1], h = 0.1; y2 = x^2- 2х + 8 на отрезке [-1; 1 ], h = 0.2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double first_y(double x);
double second_y(double x);
    
void main() {
         setlocale(0, "");
         double a1 = 0.1, b1 = 1, a2 = -1, b2 = 1, y1, y2, min1 = a1, min2 = a2, h1 = 0.1, h2 = 0.2;
         cout << "Функция y = sin^2(x) * cos(x) - ln(|x|)\n";
         cout << "Шаг: " << h1;
         while (a1 <= b1){
             y1= first_y(a1);
             a1 += h1;
            }
         if (min1 >= y1) min1 = y1;
         cout << "Минимальное первой функции: " << min1 << endl;
         cout << "Функция y = x^2 - 2x + 8\n";
         cout << "Шаг: " << h2;
         while (a2 <= b2){
             y2 = second_y(a2);
             a2 += h2;
             }
         if (min2 >= y2) min2 = y2; 
         cout << "Минимальное второй функции: " << min2 << endl;
            }
    double first_y(double x) {
         if (x == 0) return 0;
         if (x!=0) return pow(sin(x), 2) * cos(x) - log(abs(x));
            }
    double second_y(double x) {
         return pow(x, 2) - 2 * x + 8;
            }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: Просто не понимаю в чём проблема, после запуска программы она просто ломается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, у вас много несуразностей, типа `void main()`... Или вы пробегаете все значения, и только последнее сравниваете с минимальным

```
while (a1 <= b1){
     y1= first_y(a1);
     a1 += h1;
}
if (min1 >= y1) min1 = y1;
```

Да и само значение `min1` у вас не значение функции, а минимальное значение ее аргумента. Словом, вы складываете 3 килограмма и 2 метра, и хотите получить 5 ампер...

Да, у меня (VC++ 2019) программа не ломается. Но, понятно, выдает неверные ответы.

Я бы ее переделал следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double first_y(double x);
double second_y(double x);

double get_min(double(*f)(double), double a, double b, double h)
{
    double min = f(a);
    for( ;a < b + h/2; a+=h)
    {
        double y = f(a);
        if (min > y) min = y;
    }
    return min;
}

int main()
{

    cout << "Функция y = sin^2(x) * cos(x) - ln(|x|)\n";
    cout << "Минимальное значение: " << get_min(first_y,0.1,1,0.1) << "\n\n";
    cout << "Функция y = x^2 - 2x + 8\n";
    cout << "Минимальное значение: " << get_min(second_y,-1,1,0.2) << "\n\n";
}

double first_y(double x)
{
    double y = cos(x);
    return y*(1-y*y)-log(abs(x));
}
double second_y(double x)
{
    return (x - 2) * x + 8;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое